# Dimension of space of matrices $X$ such that $AXB=0$, in terms of the ranks of $A$ and $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $r$ and $B$ a $p\times q$ matrix of rank $s$. Find the dimension of the vector space of $n\times p$ matrices $X$ such that $AXB=0$

I know that We have $AXB=0\iff {\rm Im}(XB)\subset \ker (A)$ From this I could not proceed. Any idea will be welcome

Comment: Channeling Sylvester, we can observe that the linear map $X\mapsto AXB$ is represented by the tensor product $A\otimes B^T$, whose rank is $rs$. You're looking for the nullity, which is $np-rs$.

Answer (score 1):

We can bring the matrices $A$ and $B$ to forms canonical under [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence#Canonical_form):

$$A=MRN,\quad B=PSQ,$$

where $M,N,P,Q$ are square invertible matrices (with $m$, $n$, $p$, $q$ rows correspondingly) and $R$, $S$ are matrices with every element zero except a part of the main diagonal ($r$ and $s$ entries), which is ones. Now $AXB=0 \Leftrightarrow MR(NXP)SQ = 0 \Leftrightarrow R(NXP)S = 0$. The set $\{NXP | AXB = 0\}$ is a linear space of the same dimension as $\{X|AXB=0\}$, so we need only solve the equation $R\hat XS=0\quad (*)$.

Then $R\hat XS = (\sum\limits_{k=1}^r E_{kk})(\sum\limits_{1\le i\le n\\1\le j \le p} \hat x_{ij} E_{ij})(\sum\limits_{l=1}^s E_{ll})$, where $E_{ij}$ are the matrix units.

**Edit**. The product written above is a matrix of zeros, except the top left $r \times s$ corner which is filled with distinct entries from $\hat X$. For $(*)$ to hold, the entries that end up in the corner should be zero, and all other ones can be arbitrary. So we get the same answer as in *blargoner*'s comment, which would be preferable to my elementary method in case you know about Kronecker products of matrices.

Comment: Can you please give a detailed solution ?

Comment: @rubi76re Added a paragraph.